# Get the list of windows for running application on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I used samples from [CGWindow API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CGWindow_Reference/Reference/Functions.html) and [SonOfGrab](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004490) samples to get the windows list and grab them, in particularly I used `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` for retrieving the list of windows along with `CGWindowListOption` specified. However I have a problem here. The thing is that I only want to see the list of windows which belong to a running applications, i.e. I don't want to get windows for dock, system menu etc.

I tried to set `kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements` and `kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly` flags, they removed some windows I'm not interested in, however even with these options set, I still have 'Dropbox icon in menu bar' window, dock window, system panel window etc. Is there a way to filter them out?

I also tried to request `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApps]` to get the list of running applications. My idea was to get the process identifiers from `runningApps` and remove from the list of windows those ones who don't have process identifiers from the `runningApps` list. Unfortunately it didn't work out, since the list of running applications is way bigger than I expected and it also contains dashboard applications and other things. I tried to find a property or something like this to distinguish between these 'system apps' and 'real apps', however I wasn't able to achieve this.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Filter by window level?

Comment: @Willeke, I had this idea in mind, I've noticed that all windows I'm not interested in have layer number 25, 26 etc, while the others (which I'm interested in) have layer number 0. Do you know which this window layer represents? Is it a safe way to filter the windows I'm interested in? Should I ignore all windows whose level is bigger than 0?

Comment: If it isn't documented, it isn't safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could:

- get the bundle for a running application
- check its plist for if it is has a UIElement key -> those wouldn't be in the dock

=> then filter the windows against the remaining PIDs

Comment: do you mean to request a bundle url and then open the Info.plist in BUNDLE_URL/Contents/Info.plist? Hm. I tried this on couple applications - this approach worked. Thanks! Is it a safe solution? Is it an 'official' way to solve such problems or more like workaround? (I just want to make sure that the application will work with different Mac OS X versions and won't make any unexpected results)

Comment: It isn't official but it sounds safe. Of course not with sandboxing (!)

Comment: Ok, got it. Is the location of Info.plist is standardised? Is it always placed in BUNDLE_PATH/Info.plist?

Comment: yes. but you even use NSBundle. objectForInfoDictionaryKey

Comment: Ah, you mean initialize NSBundle with path received from NSRunningApplication and then use objectForInfoDictionaryKey to get the value for the value, right? - Good advice, thanks.

Comment: By the way, is the "LSUIElement" key is an official key that remains consistent along different Mac OS X versions?

Comment: Yes. It is socumented like that